# python ValueError:need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, brute-force

the problem

> username, password = line.strip().split(":")
>   ValueError:need more than 1 value to unpack

this is the script

```
print '[+] Bruteforcing against %s with dictionary %s' % (ip, filename)
for line in fd.readlines():
    username, password = line.strip().split(":")
    t = threading.Thread(target=attempt, args=(ip,username,password))
```

Comment: Is the file you are reading on empty ? It looks like you're trying to give a value to two variables at the same time but split only returns one result

Comment: The problem is there is no `:` in `line`

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from an opened file line by line, each lines are stored temporarily in a variable "line".Then, after removing all whitespaces at the start and end of each line ,you tried to split this line into two parts, one is left part before character ':' and another is right part after character ':',  and store them into two variables "username" and "password".

Here the possible reason for error is that you are trying to split the line into two parts considering character ':' exists. What happens if the character ':' does not exist in line. This is the possible reason for the type of error you got.

My suggestion is that try to check if character exists in the line, if it exist then try to split line

For example you can simply check:

```
if line.find(':')!=-1: 
   username, password = line.strip().split(":")
```